# Stopwatch class for Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, stopwatch

Is there a stopwatch Class (preferably opensource) providing the same service as `Diagnostics.TStopwatch` in Delphi XE does?

Comment: Try this http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm

Comment: @RRUZ: Very good resource but I am not sure of its license status. I can accept it as an aswer if you migrate it.

Comment: You can ask to Zarko directly by the license usage, but I don't think  which this code have any restriction.

Comment: @RRUZ: Thank you. I am going to ask him by mail. I will edit my post to soften the opensource requirement.

Comment: I actually had some DELL motherboards where the High Resolution Timer API as shown by Zarko behaved weirdly; it had some serious glitches in it, thanks to some low level Windows kernel bugs and chipset driver bugs (Intel) to the point that GetTickCount was actually more accurate.   That appears no longer to happen on modern Core2Duo dell machines, but it was a big problem on Pentium4 era Dells (2006-ish) on both Windows XP and Vista.

Comment: @WarrenP The P4 machines were probably getting time wrong because the processors were too busy flushing and reloading the netburst instruction pipelines because that's all those rotten nasty heaps of junk ever did!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference goes to [this](http://www.delphipraxis.net/134663-tstopuhr-kleine-klasse-zur-zeitmessung.html) (**TStopUhr**) implementation found in [Delphi Praxis](http://www.delphipraxis.net/) forum.

Excerpt:

```
type
  TStopUhr = class
     private
       FStoppedTime : Int64;
       FStartValue : Int64;
       FStopValue : Int64;
       FStartTime : TDateTime;
       FStopTime : TDateTime;
       FMethode : TStopUhrMethode;
       FMethodeInUse : TStopUhrMethode;
     protected
       function GetStoppedTimeStr: String;
     public
       Constructor Create;
       Destructor Destroy; Override;
       procedure Start;
       procedure Stop;
       property StartTime : TDateTime read FStartTime;
       property StopTime : TDateTime read FStopTime;
       property StoppedTime : Int64 read FStoppedTime;
       property StoppedTimeStr : String read GetStoppedTimeStr;
       property MeasureMethode : TStopUhrMethode Read FMethode Write FMethode;
     end;
```

Usage sample:

```
var
   StopUhr : TStopUhr;
 begin
   StopUhr := TStopUhr.Create;
   StopUhr.MeasureMethode := su_TickCount; // default = su_DateTime
   StopUhr.Start;

  // zu messende Aufgabe

  StopUhr.Stop;
   ShowMessage(StopUhr.StoppedTimeStr);
   StopUhr.Free;
 end;
```

It provides a similar functionality to what [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) recommended in the question's comment thread.

Answer (score 3):

[JCLCounter from Project Jedi](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aTJclCounter) is very similar to TStopwatch.

Answer (score 2):

I realize it's low tech, but the Win32 API `GetTickCount` function works well enough for me.  On most PCs the resolution is around 15-20 milliseconds.

I use it like this, without any classes, but you could easily write your own class:

```
function TimerElapsed(tick1,tick2:DWORD):DWORD;
begin
  if ((tick2-tick1) < $80000000) then { timer roll-over check }
      result := (tick2 - tick1) { normal }
  else
      result := (not tick1)+tick2; {rollover calculation}
end;

function TimingDemo:Cardinal;
var 
  time1,time2:Cardinal;
begin
   time1 := GetTickCount;
   DoSomethingSlow;
   time2 := GetTickCount;
   result  :=  TimerElapsed(time1,time2); // return elapsed mSec.
end;
```

Comment: I use a slightly different algorithm for calculating the elapsed time: `function TimerElapsed(tick1,tick2:DWORD):DWORD; 
begin 
  if tick2 >= tick1 then { timer roll-over check } 
      Result := (tick2 - tick1) { normal } 
  else 
      Result := (MAXDWORD - tick1) + tick2; {rollover calculation} 
end; 
`

Comment: I think that MAXDWORD-tick1 and NOT tick1 will do the same thing. Both do a 1s complement (logical NOT).